# is it possible to move from asp.net validators to jQuery validators

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

is it possible to move from asp.net validations to j Query validations without much effort .I also need a validation summary like control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using jQuery validation with ASP.NET WebForms](http://encosia.com/2009/11/04/using-jquery-validation-with-asp-net-webforms/).